# Restore mysql databases from .MYD .MYI and .SDI files

Tags: mysql

My mysql server got corrupted because of a bad InnoDB file which I've tried numerous times to recover, but nothing has worked. I have all of the backed-up table data from before I reinstalled MariaDB, but I can't figure out how to restore the databases. I have the MYD, MYI, and SDI files from every database. I know I could recreate the structures by hand, but I have a lot of tables which would take a long time to rebuild. What is the easiest way I can restore all of these tables? I have the following directory structure saved:

```
\_database1
    \_table1
    \_table2
\_database2
    \_table3
    \_table4
    \_table5
\_database3
    \_table6
```

etc.

Ideally, I'd like to convert these to a more standardized format like .CSV or .SQL, so I would settle for a converter also. I see such a thing [exists for MyISAM](https://www.rebasedata.com/convert-myisam-to-mysql-online), but not InnoDB.

Comment: This is a question for [dba.se]. I realise this is late advice, but you should always take your backups with `mysqldump`

Comment: SDI files are JSON files, containing the metadata for the tables. See https://blogs.oracle.com/mysql/post/mysql-80-all-you-need-to-know-about-sdi for full explanation. But I don't know of a convenient tool to recover a CREATE TABLE from this file. You may have to invent such a tool, or write each CREATE TABLE statement manually.

Comment: SDI are MySQL, but you say "reinstalled MariaDB"? Did the error messages happen to look like those in [MDEV-27882](https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-27882). If you you can't install MariaDB over MySQL-8.0. Recommend going back to MySQL-8.0 and your data may still be in a good start. If you want to do a  MariaDB migration start with a `mysqldump` of databases and load those into a test MariaDB instance.

Comment: @danblack I tried using mysql8 originally which is what I had to begin with, but so many packages got corrupted it was easier to reinstall the db as MariaDB after redoing the whole system more than twice. I tried fixing it before removing MySQL, but I couldn't get mysqldump to work because of the corrupted innodb files, same thing with innodb recovery mode.